# ksoap2 evelope.getResponse gets a nullpointerException

Tags: exception, soap, nullpointerexception, ksoap2

Ok, here is my Problem:

I am sending a soap-Request and i get a valid answer, everything is correctly working and i get the valid output within the responsedump.
But calling evelope.getResponse() in:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
//adding parameters
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapObject so = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

throws this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:521)
```

the Error is within the getResponse
from the source of ksoap2:

/**
 * Response from the soap call. Pulls the object from the wrapper object and returns it.
 *
 * @since 2.0.3
 * @return response from the soap call.
 * @throws SoapFault
 */

```
public Object getResponse() throws SoapFault {
    if (bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
        throw (SoapFault) bodyIn;
    }
    KvmSerializable ks = (KvmSerializable) bodyIn; <-- Line 521

if (ks.getPropertyCount()==0) {
    return null;
} else if(ks.getPropertyCount()==1) {
    return ks.getProperty(0);
} else {
    Vector ret = new Vector();
    for(int i=0;i<ks.getPropertyCount();i++){
        ret.add(ks.getProperty(i));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

Comment: How did you finally manage to solve this problem?

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem so i parsed the output manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead of SoapObject

```
 SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: Sadly, the Error is in getRespose() and not in the Object returned.
There is nothing returned because of the Error at Line 521 (edited post)

Comment: did u check the bodyin,                                         SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;                    String response = result.getProperty(0).toString();

Comment: means you are not getting anything as a response

Comment: Seems so, but printing androidHttpTransport.responseDump gives me the valid Response just how the Server should respond

Comment: Do you have any idea why this stays null?

Comment: The lastest version 3.3 ksoap2 should have fixed this issue